# Db First Model > Association > Then "Will not round-trip"

Tags: entity-framework

This is my first time working with Entity Framework so it is highly likely despite trying to read and follow everything I can carefully I've missed something along the way and there is something pretty obvious to of you experienced with EF.

What I have are 4 tables that are assembled into a EF model that is DB first based. As soon as I had pulled them in I defined 3 associations linking the four tables together.  The relationship to each other is pretty straight forward as a hierarchy. Moving from left to right there is a one to many relationship to each subsequent table:
[The lay model layout out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0SKo.jpg)

### Now the field assiated may not seem so obvious by the names so let me lay that out here:

```
SecFamily.FAMILIES ---> GETT_Family_Group_List.ARSFamily
   GETT_Family_Group_List.ARSDocTag ---> GET_Elements.Article
      GET_Elements.EID ---> GETT_Documents.EIDref
```

So after making these associations I did build to see where I was and whoa Nelly! Didn't expect to see this:
[Error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcYnE.jpg)

Key in this that baffles me most is "An Entity with Key (PK) will not round-trip when:" being the issue here.  I'm not the least bit interested in round tripping.  All I want to do is drill into the depth not tunnel back up again.

So did I miss something along the way?  I'd like to turn off the round trip obligation if I could maybe or at least find out what it takes to deal with this as the interface didn't' seem to indicate any issue that I'd over looked.

Thanks,
Ken

Comment: All your errors seem to be caused by unspecified mappings. Your model's properties (DDL) don't link to database columns (SSDL). In general, unless you have masochistic tendencies, simply don't create models and associations by hand, but remove them and let the entire model be generated by choosing "Update Model from Database...", selecting the relevant tables and finishing the wizard. This will fix your entire EDMX.

Comment: Okay... I can do that but as they came in with no relationship I'm wondering why that would help but I'll give it a shot. Thanks.

Comment: If there are no relations in the database (foreign keys), that won't help. Then you can still let the wizard generate both sides of the models, but you'll have to add the relations yourself. Also make sure to have a backup of your work on the model before throwing it away.

Comment: By George it worked!   I'm not sure how it did it but it did!... Thanks CC!

Comment: Well, welcome to the entity framework club. It's a love-hate thing.

Comment: I see what you mean about the love-hate relationship... Last night I went home all excited about what I'd seen just before leaving for the day. This morning I come back an load up the project and what do I see?? THIS!!

Comment: I see what you mean about the love-hate relationship... Last night I went home all excited about what I'd seen just before leaving for the day. This morning I come back an load up the project and what do I see?? THIS x 5 !!
Error 111: There is no property with name 'SecFamilyFAMILIES' defined in type referred by Role 'GETT_Family_Group_List'. C:\Users\B18833\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\GETTWeb\GETTWeb\GETTDataModel.edmx 205

So I'm off on another adventure this morning...Regards, Ken Carter

Comment: seems like this is telling you you are missing a navigation property.

Comment: Not sure.. nothing changed overnight... just trying to figure it out now... I thought that perhaps because I hadn't defined where I would be using the four tables that was the issue but as I am trying to figure that out that doesn't seem to help either.